# JS regex replace contents in only in the first block of repeating blocks

Tags: javascript, regex, html

I'm trying to implement an simple templateing enging in javascript. I'm trying to fill the template with regular expressions.

Is it possible to safely only replace the first occurance of a template-block while leaving the second unattached? How must the regex look for this like?

I do have a template with building blocks like the following (in reallity a little bit more complex since blocks look differently):

```
<template-block>
  <h1>%%a%%</h1>
  <img src="%%b%%" />
</template-block>
<template-block>
  <h1>%%a%%</h1>
  <img src="%%b%%" />
  <p>%%c%%</p>
</template-block>
<template-block>
  <h1>%%a%%</h1>
  <img src="%%b%%" />
  <p>%%c%%</p>
</template-block>
```

The replacement right now is done through the following expresisons

```
html = html.replace(/(<template-block>.+?)%%a%%(.*<\/template-block>)/gim,"$1"+a+"$2");
html = html.replace(/(<template-block>.+?)%%b%%(.*<\/template-block>)/gim,"$1"+b+"$2");
html = html.replace(/(<template-block>.+?)%%c%%(.*<\/template-block>)/gim,"$1"+c+"$2");
html = html.replace(/(<template-block>)([\s\S]+?)(<\/template-block>)/gim,"$2");
```

However this regular expressions causes problems e.g. while replacing the first block since there %%c%% is missing and thus %%c%% is replaced in the second block. However I'm not able to make `<template>` lacy to only match the first occurance of it.

Comment: The problem is not clear. Please add the exact desired output you would want given the input shown.

Comment: Only replace block one. Than block one is done strpe <template-block> and </template-block> out and continue with block two

Comment: Please add the *text* of the exact desired output to the question, in a text block at the bottom. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply proceed in 2 steps:

1. Match the entire first block.
2. Process its content to replace your placeholder(s).

Then you can re-inject the new content, removing the `template-block` tags at the same time.

```js
var re = /(<template-block>)([\s\S]*?)(<\/template-block>)/i,
    a = "aa", // whatever value you need.
    b = "bb",
    c = "cc",
    newHtml;

function processFirstBlock(text) {
    var firstBlockContent = re.exec(text),
        innerContent;

    if (firstBlockContent && firstBlockContent.length) {
        // firstBlockContent[2] is what is matched with ([\s\S]*?)
        innerContent = firstBlockContent[2];
        innerContent = innerContent.
            replace(/(%%a%%)/gi, a).
            replace(/(%%b%%)/gi, b).
            replace(/(%%c%%)/gi, c);

        // firstBlockContent[0] is the entire match.
        // [1] and [3] are the opening and closing tags, so drop them.
        text = text.replace(firstBlockContent[0], innerContent);

        return text;
    }

    return false;
}

newHtml = processFirstBlock(html);

while (newHtml) {
    html = newHtml;
    newHtml = processFirstBlock(html);
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/o7tdycme/